# Swift deep NSObjects do not compile

Tags: swift, swift2, trie

In Swift, I am trying to implement a word Trie, using a literal representation as a series of nested NSObjects. Here is the Trie.

```
let GEENITRIE:NSObject = [
    "i":[
            "need":[
                    "tutoring":[
                            "in":[
                                    "**ARG**":"{courserequest}"]],
                    "a":[
                            "tutoring":[
                                    "session":[
                                            "in":[
                                                    "**ARG**":"{courserequest}"]]]]],
            "want":[
                    "tutoring":[
                            "in":[
                                    "**ARG**":"{courserequest}"]]],
            "would":[
                    "like":[
                            "tutoring":[
                                    "in":[
                                            "**ARG**":"{courserequest}"]]]]],
    "tutoring":[
            "in":[
                    "**ARG**":"{coureserequest}",
                    "and":[
                            "**ARG**":"{doublecourse}"]],
            "at":[
                    "**ARG**":"{timeparse}"]],
    "a":[
            "tutoring":[
                    "session":[
                            "in":[
                                    "**ARG**":"{courserequest}"],
                            "at":[
                                    "**ARG**":"{timeparse}"]]]]]
```

However, when I compile this with the rest of my command line app, it takes about 26 seconds, then the following error comes up: `Error:(23, 26) expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

Why does this happen, and what is the best way to implement this so this does not happen?

Comment: How do you use JSON in swift?

Comment: This is simply a limitation of the Swift compiler, which is currently not fast/efficient enough to handle complex expressions. You should try breaking your code up into smaller dictionaries which you combine together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the Swift compiler has to figure out the real type of that expression, and figuring it out might take too long.

You should move your data into a file in JSON format:

```
 {
  "i":{
       "need":{
               "tutoring":{
                           "in":{
                                 "**ARG**":"{courserequest}"}},
               "a":{
                    "tutoring":{
                                "session":{
                                           "in":{
                                                 "**ARG**":"{courserequest}"}}}}},
       "want":{
               "tutoring":{
                           "in":{
                                 "**ARG**":"{courserequest}"}}},
       "would":{
                "like":{
                        "tutoring":{
                                    "in":{
                                          "**ARG**":"{courserequest}"}}}}},
  "tutoring":{
              "in":{
                    "**ARG**":"{coureserequest}",
                    "and":{
                           "**ARG**":"{doublecourse}"}},
              "at":{
                    "**ARG**":"{timeparse}"}},
  "a":{
       "tutoring":{
                   "session":{
                              "in":{
                                    "**ARG**":"{courserequest}"},
                              "at":{
                                    "**ARG**":"{timeparse}"}}}}}
```

Then load it at runtime:

```
let jsonUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("data", withExtension: "json")!
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: jsonUrl)!
let tree = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run across the same error. You could break the structure out into its own JSON file and read from there, or build from smaller dictionaries that you then add together (breaking the expression up, as suggested). Since your data isn't fixed the latter is likely better.